# Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, pip, installation

I'm trying to use pip to install a package.  I try to run `pip install` from the Python shell, but I get a `SyntaxError`.  Why do I get this error?  How do I use pip to install the package?

```
>>> pip install selenium
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you can do it with [IPython](https://ipython.org) interpreter (same syntax as the question :`>>> pip install selenium`). not in regular Python interpreter. but it's still better to install pip packages with the terminal.

Comment: Several of the answers here explain what you could do to force the `pip` command to work from within Python, but the simple beginner answer is, don't do that; run the `pip` command (or any other command which produces a SyntaxError in Python) at your command prompt, not in Python.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

pip is run from the command line, not the Python interpreter. It is a program that **installs** modules, so you can use them from Python. Once you have installed the module, then you can open the Python shell and do `import selenium`.

The Python shell is not a command line, it is an interactive interpreter. You type Python code into it, not commands.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I still can't get it to run. Where exactly is it? It is giving me a "pip is not recognized" error (because I'm not the right dir). It was installed in \site-packages but I'm looking thought it and I can't find any pip.exe

Comment: @Nacht - `pip` will be in the scripts directory of your python install so you will want to add it to your path. Add `C:\Python32\scripts` to your `PATH`. Change the path as necessary based on where you installed it.

Comment: Actually pip.exe in windows is an python script as others in /scripts directory, but wraped in exe to run it with default python interpreter. By opening pip.exe with 7-zip you can see _main_.py importing pip, sys and re modules... (And there you'll find the answer how to run it within a python shell)--> pip is a regular python module. Don't forget windows wasn't first platform supporting python, linux was, and there python is a part of OS.

Comment: I know for me I had to do this from the command line (not python command line). This was after changing directory to the location of python.exe and then needed to put the file type on pip3. In my case I was after requests for HTTP work. Namely:

python pip3.exe install requests <--- this worked perfectly, repeated the same for pytz module

Comment: @natur3 That's crazy stuff. Python would not know how to run a compiled native binary `.exe` file as a script. If this really worked, there's probably something more to your story.

Comment: This answer is somewhat outdated in modern Jupyter. You can run pip inside a cell in Jupyter notebooks now and **not just the command line outside Jupyter**. You should be using the magic install variation. `%pip install <package_name>`. That will insure installation in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. (Exclamation point won't necessarily do that.) **Because in modern Jupyter automagics is usually on in general, without any symbol in the front the magic version will get run behind-the-scenes.**  ...

Comment: <continued> See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: Jupyter is it's own special magic thing, not simply just a python interpreter, which is the topic of this question.

Answer (score 129):

Use the command line, not the Python shell (DOS, PowerShell in Windows).

```
C:\Program Files\Python2.7\Scripts> pip install XYZ
```

If you installed Python into your PATH using the latest installers, you don't need to be in that folder to run pip

Terminal in Mac or Linux

```
$ pip install XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks for including the C:...., helped me realize where I needed to cd to as you cant simply open command line and type pip.

Comment: FYI I the Python install I just did did NOT set the `PATH`. I had to do this manually, pointing to the install path in `%APPDATA%`

Comment: @hammythepig that will depend on your system configuration.

Comment: The dollar sign is traditionally used as part of the Bourne shell (and hence Bash etc) prompt, but this is completely configurable. Many people will see `bash$` or perhaps `hal:~ you$` etc. MacOS now defaults to Zsh which typically has `%` instead of `$` and probably also various additional decorations like `you@grannysmith ~ %`

Answer (score 67):

As @sinoroc suggested correct way of installing a package via pip is using separate process since pip may cause closing a thread or may require a restart of interpreter to load new installed package so this is the right way of using the API: `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'SomeProject'])` but since Python allows to access internal API and you know what you're using the API for you may want to use internal API anyway eg. if you're building own GUI package manager with alternative resourcess like https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

**Following soulution is OUT OF DATE, instead of downvoting suggest updates.** see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7498 for reference.

---

**UPDATE**: **Since pip version 10.x** there is no more `get_installed_distributions()` or `main` method under `import pip` **instead use** `import pip._internal as pip`.

**UPDATE ca. v.18** `get_installed_distributions()` has been removed. Instead you may use generator `freeze` like this:

```py
from pip._internal.operations.freeze import freeze

print([package for package in freeze()])

# eg output ['pip==19.0.3']
```

---

If you want to use pip inside the Python interpreter, try this:

```
import pip

package_names=['selenium', 'requests'] #packages to install
pip.main(['install'] + package_names + ['--upgrade']) 
# --upgrade to install or update existing packages
```

If you need to update every installed package, use following:

```
import pip

for i in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    pip.main(['install', i.key, '--upgrade'])
```

If you want to stop installing other packages if any installation fails, use it in one single `pip.main([])` call:

```
import pip

package_names = [i.key for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
pip.main(['install'] + package_names + ['--upgrade'])
```

**Note**: When you install from list in file with `-r` / `--requirement` parameter you do NOT need open() function.

```
pip.main(['install', '-r', 'filename'])
```

**Warning**: Some parameters as simple `--help` may cause python interpreter to stop.

Curiosity: By using `pip.exe` you actually use python interpreter and pip module anyway. If you unpack `pip.exe` or `pip3.exe` regardless it's python 2.x or 3.x, inside is the SAME single file `__main__.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: This works in the Python shell, so I think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find when Googling this problem.

Comment: Great answer, and it should definitely be included here, but I disagree it should be the accepted answer, since the user was clearly trying to make the now ubiquitous syntax "pip install" work.  Since that syntax will not work with this method, it does not directly solve that issue.  It may be more useful than the accepted answer though :)

Comment: No idea what was really meant by OP, but this answer was really late answer, so it's not important if it's the accepted here.

Comment: @Zydnar, agreed--my response was to Francois, who said this should be the accepted answer.  I posted my reasoning as to why not.  That said, I still think this is a great post.

Comment: This also is a remedy for the problem with pip3 failing here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885#issuecomment-307696027   Import pip a second time if there is an error the first time.  Then use the procedure in this answer to install packages from inside the Python interpreter.

Comment: This just doesn't answer the question. This doesn't mention anything about the "syntax error". Then it suggests code that uses private, internal APIs, which is obviously [bad practice](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). If at least it mentioned the right way of calling pip: `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'SomeProject'])`...

Comment: @sinoroc when I first posted the answer it wasn't private API, than someone asked to update the question and deleted the comment, yes it is a bad practice, however Python allows on that since there is no real encapsulation in this language and as the creator of Python said - programmers are not kids. We don't know the whole context.

Comment: I omit the update info about "import pip._internal as pip" the first time I see your answer,  how about  write it as a comment in the code place?

Comment: @tinyhare maby you're right. Without it it was solution for versions under 10.x - I will try make it more clear to everyone.

Answer (score 61):

To run pip in Python 3.x, just follow the instructions on Python's page: [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/).

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

or (if python 2 and python 3 are on the same system):

```
python3 -m pip install SomePackage
```

Note that this is run from the command line and not the python shell (the reason for syntax error in the original question).

Comment: I'm still receiving invalid syntax.  I'm using IPython on a Windows 10 pc.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This page has instructions for installing IPython: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html  $ pip install ipython.  Presumably that would translate to $ python -m pip install ipython

Comment: worked for me on windows 10 - also advised me to upgrade pip as per previous comment :)

Comment: @DataGirl Then you still need to notice the last paragraph: the syntax error comes from running the command in Python; it is not valid Python code, so it raises a syntax error. You need to run it on your command prompt (CMD or Powershell on Windows; Bash, Zsh etc on other platforms).

Comment: On some platforms, you need `python3` instead of `python`

Answer (score 2):

same issue is in `jupyter-notebook`. if you execute `pip install ...` in a cell on its own, it executes but if there is a comment line in the beginning it does not work.

[image]

I think when Jupyter sees the comment line in the beginning, it treats the cell as a Python interpreter and raises the error.

Comment: For sake of completeness, I'm going to point out the behind-the-scenes modern Jupyter generally will be running the magic variation of the install command because automagics are on in general. In other words, the second cell shown is equivalent to `%pip install pdf2image`. It is in general better to be explicit when putting such commands in your own notebooks so you & others will know what is happening, or be prodded to look into it. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands.

Answer (score -1):

you need to type it in cmd not in the IDLE. becuse IDLE is not an command prompt if you want to install something from IDLE type this

```
>>>from pip.__main__ import _main as main
>>>main(#args splitted by space in list example:['install', 'requests'])
```

this is calling pip like `pip <commands>` in terminal. The commands will be seperated by spaces that you are doing there to.

Comment: This is outdated answer since about pip version 10.0. `ImportError: cannot import name main` using pip v19.0.3