# Invalid syntax in Python when trying to use mkdir

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to learn Python from a tutorial. I'm supposed to create a folder using `mkdir`, but when I try that, I see this result:

```
> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> mkdir mystuff
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    mkdir mystuff
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I couldn't figure this out from the tutorial. What is wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is functionally the same problem as [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030), but that question was asked narrowly (and attracted some answers that missed the point or buried the lede).

Answer (score 5):

The command `mkdir mystuff` needs to be used from the system command line, not Python.

Answer (score 2):

To [create a new folder from within Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192), use:

```
import os
os.mkdir(path)
```

To [run the shell command from within Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228), use:

```
os.system('mkdir path')
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running the mkdir command, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to exit Python. It should look like this:

```
> python
ActivePython 2.6.5.12 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Mar 20 2010, 14:22:52) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 
on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z
> mkdir mystuff
> cd mystuff
```

The screen will [display `^Z` to indicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Exit from Python first by typing `quit()` and pressing the Enter key, and then use the `mkdir mystuff` command. This command should be used outside of python.

Answer (score -1):

`mkdir` is used at the command line to make a directory (folder). For example, `mkdir mystuff` makes a directory named `mystuff`.

This needs to be run with the command line, not python.