# Python pip install SyntaxError

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I have installed `pip` and it said it was a success. Now I try to do `pip install` but it gives me a syntax error on the word install. I have looked about and everyone is writing that, but for some reason I'm getting an error.

```
pip install deap
```

That is exactly what I'm typing and I'm getting a syntax error on the word "install".

Comment: please post the full error output.

Comment: are you using `pip install` from the command line or the Python interpreter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" raise a SyntaxError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: >>> pip install deap
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You cannot use pip install on the Python interpreter use it on the command line. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548165/797495

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the screenshot below friend.

1. You must go to windows cmd
2. Direct your `PATH` to the folder where 'Scripts' is held.

for me it was

`c:\python27\scripts`

3. Once you've done that you should be ready to rock n roll

[image]