# Unable to install twilio using pip in python 3.4.3 on windows 10

Tags: python, installation, pip, twilio

I have downloaded Python 3.4.3 and I am trying to install `twilio` using the Python command line by typing

```
install pip twillio
```

I'm unable to use pip to install any other module in python. When I try to install `twilio`, I get an error saying

```
INVALID SYNTAX
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" raise a SyntaxError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the installation instructions for the [twilio-python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install#installation) helper library: 
`install pip twilio` is not a valid command. The correct command is `pip install twilio`.

If you are getting an invalid syntax error, it sounds like you might be running this command in the Python interpreter rather than the command line. The Python shell can only handle code, not commands like `pip`, so try typing this in the command line instead. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-raise-a-syntaxerror).

Comment: Still not working im typing in command line only
pip install twillio
giving syntax error