# How do I upgrade pip on python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm a complete newbie, giving my first baby steps into programming and automation testing. I have Python 2.7.12 installed and pip version 8.1.1 with it. I want to update pip but all the commands provided by many users (while I was searching about this subject) don't work, like for example:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip (doesn't recognize pip)
```

or

```
pip -V
```

[python window - nameerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUp7B.jpg)

Sure I'm making a terrible newbie mistake... Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your os?

Comment: Instead of `pip -V`, use `pip -v`

Comment: It seems you are using Windows. did you try the method suggested on ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: That answer is Python3, though. which as a new Python developer, you should use anyway. But you've ran that command from the Python interpreter, not your OS command line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: @cricket_007 you could set the path for Python2 as well in the same manner.

Comment: my os is Windows 7

Comment: @madjo try the link I posted before.

Comment: @Shagun Sodhani Thank you, that was it, after setting the correct path I was able to use the command "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" and it did successfully upgrade pip! Thank you all very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

Python does not maintain version 2.7 now;
it prompts：

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st,
> 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021.
> More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

To solve this problem, use

```
easy_install pip==20.3.4
```

(python version used: 2.7.13)

4.21.2021

Run as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Try Using :-

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

because on certain versions of windows/python, **python** is not recognized as an valid command.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
$ curl -fsSL -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py --no-python-version-warning && rm -f get-pip.py
$ python -m pip --version
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct path in your windows command line like (in my case):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\iyv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\iyv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pip
```

Otherwise you could try installing an interpreter like PyCharm, and doing the update through their platform.