# How to change environment on python shell (pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to use anaconda on **windows** and I want to do a pip install using the python console in pycharm. However, I'm stuck on the jython environment, how do I change this my anaconda environment?

[image: Jython env]

This is what I'm trying to do with the pip install: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83vR1Nz3dHA&t=259s

Comment: You don't install from the python shell

Comment: If you want to use pip in python shell try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror/39231583#39231583

Comment: @PeterWood where do you download it from? the video tut says you should do it on the console

Comment: @Zydnar doesn't work on the jython env, how do you get out of the jython environment?

Comment: @Theo in settings in project interpreter you can install or remove packages anyway. And enviroment variables you have in settings > build, execution...> console>python console

Comment: @Zydnar the settings > build, execution...> console>python console was exactly what i was looking for, thank you! write the answer and i'll mark it as best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find enviroment variables here in settings.
[image]