# syntax error using pip on python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, syntax-error

trying to use pip to install a library is getting me a syntax error . i tried everything on the internet , the only way to install a module using pip is an answer i found here: [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)
which states:

```
import pip

package_name='selenium'
pip.main(['install', package_name])
```

is there a way to fix pip here so that i use the normal syntax like:

```
pip install somemodule
```

Some other answers where about changing the environment variables however they did not specify how to do that on Windows 7

Comment: What error? What traceback? How did you install pip? We need more to go on.

Comment: When i try pip install somemodule or some other syntax  it gives me syntax error . i didnot install pip it came with python 3.6

Comment: Did you read the *first* answer to the question you linked? The one that explains what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Or the second, for that matter?

Comment: I read it with a lot others but no other answers solved the error

Comment: It is the same link i mentioned in the question the best answer there is using the command line and i am using the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the windwos shell (cmd.exe) to install selenium using pip.

Search the directory of your python installation, inside it is a folder called scripts. Open it and in scripts hold shift and right-click. Now you get a context menu where you can choose open console in this folder (or something similar, my windows is not english).

If you have your windows shell in scripts, type:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

to get the newest pip version.

Now you can install selenium with:

`pip install selenium`

Comment: Thanks i'll try that right after i reach my pc ,sorry i can't upvote i'm new here my rep is still less 15

Comment: I know this problem, I can only comment my own answers :D