# through cmd help('modules') is showing pip in the list but while doing pip install getting Syntax Error in Windows8, Python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip, package

Through cmd help('modules') is showing pip in the list but while doing pip install getting Syntax Error in Windows8,64 bit, Python3.4

```
>>> pip install pandas
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pandas
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 2):

That error message looks like it's from the python interpreter. This means that you must `exit()` out of python before attempting to install `pandas`:

```
>>> exit()
C:\...> pip install pandas
```

However, you can install a module using python, if you *really* want to:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'pandas'])
```