# Pip in OS X 12 / Python 3.6

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I am near breaking, so I thought I would beg for help.

I would like to use pip to install python packages on my OS X machine (OS X 10.12.6).  I have tried pip install regex (example) and get the following return:

```
>>> pip install regex
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install regex
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, this is python 3.6 latest

Comment: How does your input command look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to figure it out.  Using the OS X terminal, I was able to use python3 -m pip install .

Is there a way to use pip within a python shell or do I always need to use the terminal?

Comment: yes, if you're in `ipython` you can do `!pip install blah` all commands preceded by an exclamation point will be executed in the terminal. if you are running it fro a script you will need to use `subprocess`

Comment: You can run it in a python shell, but it's a bit more complicated: first `import pip`, then you can do `pip.main(['install','regex'])`.