# Jupyter Notebook - install python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, jupyter-notebook

EDITED

I'm very new to python and have a probably super basic question. I've installed Jupyter Notebook by installing anaconda which includes python 3 by default. Now I want to use an external toolbox which still works with python 2.7, so I'm trying to get e kernel with python 2.7 as suggested [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). In the *Anaconda Prompt* I'm typing

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

But it says that it couldn't find the command "python2". Any idea?

Comment: You need to exit the Python interpreter to run bash commands

Comment: just wondering why are you still use python2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: I edited some more info to my problem. I still don't know how to use python 2 in Jupyter Notebook, the reference to the similar question doesn't really help me either.

Comment: You need a Python2 conda environment, then you can install that kernel into Jupyter. Check the link you already have... It says "if using Conda"... But again, you need to **exit** python first to run those commands

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You can try starting `jupyter-notebook` from python2

```
$ python2 /path/to/jupyter-notebook
```

in my case running `python2 /usr/bin/jupyter-notebook` fixed the issue.
[image]

[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in my case

```
$ head -1 /usr/bin/jupyter-notebook
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [Jupyter Notebook homepage](http://jupyter.org/install.html)?

Just use

```
pip install jupyter
```

or

```
pip install jupyter --user
```

Comment: That page also says *For new users, we highly recommend installing Anaconda.*

Comment: Yes, but you can install it either way... You just have to download some separate packages as mentioned on the site.

Comment: No no, I installed Jupyter Notebook by installing anaconda as @cricket_007 suggested. But it comes with python 3 and I need python 2 for an external toolbox that I want to use, as it is only compatible with python 2 unfortunately.

Comment: @SvennoNito On the Anaconda homepage you can choose between python 2.7 and python 3.6 when downloading the installer? [Homepage](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

Comment: I read somewhere else that I don't need to install Anacdona twice. I already managed to create a python 2.7 environment and to install a python 2 kernel for the Jupyter Notebook, I just wonder why the code above doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it doesn't work, but i found out what worked instead. Using

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
activate ipykernel_py2    
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

in the *Anaconda Prompt* added the option to open a python 2 notebook in the Jupyter Notebook. Also I can change the Kernel now to python 2.