# How to install SGP4 V 1.4 package in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, orbital-mechanics, sgp4

First post hear and relatively new coder. Trying to get this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sgp4/ to work, only I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm not familiar with the file extension (.tar.gz) and I don't know if this is a module or what and how to install it and get it to work. I am using python 3.6.4 currently. Apologies that this is a pretty dumb question, but I'm trying to learn towards the goal of adding to this script so that I can build a tracking capable ground station.

Any and all help appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Lorcan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using

```
pip install sgp4
```

from a terminal window? That should handle the actual download and installation for you as well as resolving any dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was confusing the interpreter with the command line window as I am used to python 2 and not 3.

If anyone else finds this searching for a solution to this problem it is explained more in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror.

Answer (score 1):

The SGP4 MATLAB version returns the satellite's state vector in four coordinate systems i.e. TEME, ITRS, GCRS, and TOD. The SGP4 Python version returns the satellite's state vector in three coordinate systems i.e. TEME, ITRS, and GCRS. You can use my Python version of SGP4 from the following link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358351066_SGP4_Python_code or you can use my MATLAB version of SGP4 from the following link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346217793_SGP4_MATLAB_code In the SGP4 Python version, it is mentioned which packages you need to install and how to install them.