# "pip install pymysql" syntax error for python 2.7.13

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm lost trying to install this package. It looks like I have it, but I can't install?

Error
[image: Error]

pip location
[image]

EDIT: I've tried running in cmd but I get another error
[cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efh7f.jpg)

[cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efh7f.jpg)

Comment: Where did you read that you should enter it into the REPL?

Comment: run pip.exe from a command prompt (not inside a python interpreter)

Comment: You typed `pip install mysql` inside the python interpreter, which is wrong.  Type it on the command line.

Comment: You have to type the command in command line, press `win` + `r` and type `cmd` to open command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: I tried it in cmd too but got another error, I edited the post to add.

Comment: @BradleyO'Hara : I have updated my answer for you new error

Comment: Please, *please* do not post screenshots of console output. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @rawing I saw that post earlier, but it doesn't address the errors I'm seeing.

Comment: @BradleyO'Hara You'll have to explain that one to me. How exactly does that not address your problem? **Edit:** I see you've edited your question, so it's now a different question. That's not my fault. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @rawing I didn't edit the question. I added the cmd error to my question to better explain my problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried it in cmd but got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to go into the folder where `pip.exe` is present. In windows, it is in `Scripts` folder:

```
cd C:\Python27\Scripts
pip install <package>
```

**Edit 1:**
You have to set the `http` and `https` proxys as:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<<your_proxy>>:<<your_port>>
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://<<your_proxy>>:<<your_port>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error still. I added to the edit

Comment: do i copy/paste that directly? Idk what my proxy and port are? Running that exactly returns "<< was unexpected at this time."

Comment: I don't know what my proxy/port are? How do I find that?

Comment: Are you working inside intranet? every company having their own proxies to communicate outside world.

Comment: I am now yes. How do I find this info?

Comment: @BradleyO'Hara Ask to your seniors