# syntax error installing a wheel with pip on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Yesterday I installed NumPy and today I am installing SciPy under Windows 7 on Python 3.6.2.  I'm using the same syntax as yesterday, but today I get "syntax error" no matter how I try this.

From the Python command prompt, I enter these two commands:

```
>>> import pip

>>> py -m pip install "C:\-- NumPy Source Code\From Christoph Goelke\scipy-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
```

That's the same syntax I used yesterday, but today I get "syntax error".

Thanks for any help on how to install this wheel on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: No, the closest the answers on that post come to my question is "python -m pip install SomePackage" which doesn't work for me.

Comment: "That's the same syntax I used yesterday" - are you sure you used that syntax in the *Python* command prompt? (and not say, in `cmd.exe` prompt?)

Comment: Earlier today I tried this from the Windows command prompt, not the Python interpreter prompt, and I got an error message re "package not found."  After I read your post, I relocated the wheel file to the command prompt's root directory (not the most elegant solution) and it was able to find it and install it.  Yesterday I did it from the Python interpreter prompt by first issuing the command "import pip."  I've noticed in all my research that few make the distinction between the two command prompts, thus causing my confusion.  Thanks for your reply.