# Python: No Pip after installing latest version

Tags: pip, python-3.6

After not being able to use pip getting an "invalid syntax" error when entering "python pip" in the CMD-Line of windows, I downloaded the latest python package from the website and installed it.
But same problem.
Even in the Python folder there is neither a pip.py nor a "get-pip.py". That's pretty weird.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: @phd No, because for somewhat reason pip isn't even installed.