# pip install python 2.7

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I want to install the `requests` module for Python 2.7.14.

I see on [this page](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pkg/requests/) that the command `$ pip install requests` installs `requests`. And I see on [this page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) that "pip is already installed if [I'm] using Python 2 >=2.7.9".

But when I run the install command above in my Python IDLE the interpreter complains about *invalid syntax*.

[image: Screenshot from IDLE]

Does anyone know why the installation is not working?

Comment: You need to run `pip` directly in the cmd prompt and not in the python console

Comment: @Rakesh thank you, I overlooked it on the tutorials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running the install command `pip install requests` in a  Python interpreter when you should be running it in a shell. Open a terminal, and then paste that command into it. Then press enter.

Then, in your Python interpreter, import the `requests` module before using it.

```
import requests

requests.get('https://www.google.com')  # For example.
```

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked the fact in the tutorials, that I have to enter the command in the shell.

Comment: @itz You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

To use the request library from inside a python interpreter you need to first use this:

```
import requests
```

If you think you may already have requests installed, try the command above from inside your python interpreter and see if it is successful.

To actually install requests using pip you need to run the command "pip install requests" from a terminal (not from within python).

Comment: I am aware of the fact that I have to Import the module before using it. But before that I need to install it ;)