# Errors with 'pip' and 'install'

Tags: python, pip, installation, openai-gym

I have python 3.5 installed on OSX, however 'pip' does not work for some reason and 'install' is a syntax error, could some body give me step by step beginners directions to get this sorted.

Comment: Could you please post the error messages. Without them, we cannot help you step by step.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to run pip from inside a script or the interactive interpreter, when you should just run it from the OS X terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Mac user, but if you have python installed in your user, try this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['pip', 'install', str(input('Name the module you wish to download:   '))])
```