# sudo -H python2 -m pip install -U pip # Update pip

Tags: python, pip

I am new in working with a kinect. I am using a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6. 
Wheneve I try to update python with :

```
sudo -H python2 -m pip install -U pip  # Update pip
```

I got this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo -H python2 -m pip install -U pip  # Update pip
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do we fix it?

Comment: why `-H`=??????

Comment: That is not python, do not run that in a python console.

Comment: Are you trying to update python or pip? pip just use - `pip install --upgrade pip`  You should also use virtual environments for python development. You can choose which python version you want when you set it up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is running a console command inside python shell,

press `ctrl+D` to exit out of python shell and then try executing the pip upgrade command

to upgrade pip using pip itself

```
pip install --upgrade pip # run in console/terminal
```

to upgrade pip using python

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip  # run in console/terminal
```

Comment: Your two examples amount to the same, if you inspect the `pip` script: it essentially execute the `pip` package, just as in your second code line. The advantage of the second version is that it's clear which Python executable is being used: too often people run into problems because `pip` doesn't correspond to the `python` being used. So I'd suggest to always use the latter approach.

Comment: MacBook-Pro-Zhenis:~ Zhenis$ sudo -H python2 -m pip install -U pip  # Update pip
sudo: python2: command not found

Comment: Note that this misses the `sudo` in the question; so there are bound to be some problems.

Comment: @AnarSarsembaeva  use `python` not `python2`

Comment: MacBook-Pro-Zhenis:~ Zhenis$ pip install --upgrade pip # run in console/terminal
-bash: pip: command not found
MacBook-Pro-Zhenis:~ Zhenis$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip  # run in console/terminal
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
MacBook-Pro-Zhenis:~ Zhenis$

Comment: @AnarSarsembaeva Try `sudo python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip` (no need for `-H`, really).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the need for `sudo` if you're just a single user on your machine. This also avoids potentially messing around with the system-wide installation.

Use

```
python2.7 -m pip install pip --upgrade --user
```

The `--user` option will install the updated `pip` package just for your user account. Everytime you use `python2.7`, it will use the newer `pip` package.
System routines will not see the newer `pip` package, nor be bothered by it.

`python2.7` is needed, because `python2` doesn't really exist: it's either `python` or `python2.7` for version 2. Python version 3 doesn't (apparently) exist by default on macOS.