# Unexpected character after line continuation in attempts to install pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip, and I cannot select the folder containing getpip.py in cmd. Whenever I try to do this, it says:

```
c:\Users\alexj\Desktop\getpip\
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    c:\Users\alexj\Desktop\getpip\
                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

You are calling pip from the python command line.

You should call it from a system command line (git bash for example).