# How to install Biopython on Mac after all options in tutorial have failed?

Tags: python, biopython

PyCharm installed and running. Biopython package downloaded and opened in PyCharm.

`pip install biopython` typed in to terminal to check, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` returned.

Running MacOS Mojave 10.14.2. `xcode-select --install` successfully installed.

Any help?

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install biopython
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install biopython
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: You need to open a terminal and type `pip`, rather than running `pip` within the Python shell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: (if you have already installed biopython then you need to `import Bio` in python to use the package)