# unable to install "user requests" in python: keep getting syntax error

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, installation

need to install 'user requests' using the command line, so I can import requests into python.

I have tried:

```
pip install --user requests
```

I've also tried every configuration of this code but I keep getting `syntax error`. I've also tried adding `$` before `pip`, using `pip37` (as I have *Python 3.7* installed) and I have tried running the command without `--user` but it still yields 'syntax error'.

Here is the full error I'm getting

```
>>>   pip install  --user requests
      File"<stdin>", line 1
         pip install --user requests
                   ^
```

The `^` keeps moving. For instance, if I enter `$ pip ...`, the `^` moves to under `$`.

I keep getting the syntax error message I mentioned above, but I expect it to install user requests so I can import requests into python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+syntaxerror

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pip, it's not in Python Interpreter but in your system

so, if you are on Linux: in the terminal, else if you are on Windows, use Powershell or Cmd and directly tap: " C:> pip install --user  request " or " C:> python -m pip install --user request "

Answer (score 0):

on Linux, directlly in the terminal " $ pip --user install" but not in the python interpreter.

N.B: "pip3" if you are python3 on Linux or "python3 -m pip "

but if you want to do this in the Python Interpreter , do :

> > > import os 
> > >       os.system('pip install --user resquest')

Comment: That worked, Gaetan; most grateful. Entered at C command line pip install requests and went like a breeze. Had been trying at the python command line!