# How to install python 3 vlc properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have installed the vlc folders from pypi, tried to write the installing code but when I try to import vlc, it says no module named vlc. And when I try to write the `pip install python-vlc` or `pip3 install python-vlc` code, it just says syntax error on 'install'. Any tips or more information about installing and importing vlc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure how many pythons you have installed in your PC, are they all python 3 or you have it both?

Let's identify which python you are using in your terminal, `python` or `python3`
Then, check it with `which pip`,`which pip3` and `which python` if you are using python, `which python3` if you are using `python3` at your terminal. Make sure your both `pip` and the `python` you use are in the same directory.

Run the `pip` or `pip3` according to the one you used :)