# pip install 'package name' command not working in Python shells

Tags: python, pip

I am new to python and I switched from Jyputer Notebook working environment to python console (python 3.8.1 shell). I am facing issue in installing packages which I was able to install/import through notebook.

`pip install dask`

`pip install pyodbc`

`pip install pysftp`

`pip install selenium`

e.g:

```
>>> pip install pysftp
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

```
>>> pip install selenium
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

While import is working for some libraries.

```
>>> import csv
```

is ok

```
>>> import pysftp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    import pysftp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysftp'
>>>
```

Comment: pip should be ran on command line and not on python interpreter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: infact manual path addtion worked for me. Go to "Control Panel\System and Security\System" path then click "Environment variables" then click "Path" the "Edit" then click "New" and your pip script path "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts" and click ok.ok.ok. –

Answer (score 3):

Pip is a utility run from your regular terminal, not a python library so it works outside of a python shell

Answer (score 2):

To install a python package, open your cmd (windows) or gnome terminal(linux):

```
pip install <package-name>
```

To install a package in your python source code, there is a deprecated method：

```
import os
os.system("pip install <package-name>")
```

Comment: >>> import os
>>> os.system("pip install pysftp")
1
>>> 
>>> import pysftp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    import pysftp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysftp'

Comment: os.system("pip install pysftp")  gives output 1 but import pysftp after this give error.

Comment: Have you installed a pip for your python?

Comment: Open your windows cmd, type: `pip list`  If not, [Installation-pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) may be useful.

Comment: I only downloaded python 3.8.1 and installed! pip list command shall be executed from which location in cmd? C:\Users\username>pip list   ?? is my default location.

Comment: You can execute it everywhere,

Comment: Sorry, you mean you installed a python with version 3.8? The package [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/#history) has stoped maintenance. It support py3.4 very well, why not change your python version into 3.7 or lower?

Comment: First you have to install pip. (See it in Liang Fan's comment how.) Run `pip list` or `os.system("pip list")` to check if pip is installed: if yes, it prints something, and `os.system` returns 0. Then you can use the os.system trick in this answer to install packages using pip. If any of the steps fail, please ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

Comment: infact manual path addtion worked for me. Go to  "Control Panel\System and Security\System" path then click  "Environment variables" then click "Path" the "Edit" then click "New" and your pip script path "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts" and click ok.ok.ok.

Answer (score 2):

Installing a pip package within a Jupyter Notebook:

```
! pip install --user <package>
```

Comment: Please add your command example here and not use links since they are not stable.

Comment: @RezaGhorbani Is it better now?