# How install discord.py library

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I want to install discord.py library, but i get the following error;

```
>>> $ pip install -U discord.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    $ pip install -U discord.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I am about to go crazy, can any pro, or just a person with some more knowledge than me help? I just want to install a simple library...

Comment: you're suppose to run that in your terminal but *not in an interactive Python session*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have tried a command line command to be executed in a Python script.
It does not work that way.

PIP is a package management tool of Python. You do not execute it from within Python this way.

What you have to do is to execute this on your normal command line (cmd, NOT in Python):

e.g. on Windows it would look like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install discord.py
C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install discord.py[voice] --> for voice support
```