# Debug Qt app with Xcode 11 and DataFormatter

Tags: qt5, xcode11

To see content of `QString`/`QList` etc. while debugging a Qt app in Xcode I set the `lldbinit-Xcode` to use the QtCreator's `lldbbridge.py`. With previous Xcode version this worked.

Using

- Xcode 11.4
- Qt 5.14.2 or 5.9.9
- Qt Creator 4.11.2
- macOS 10.15.4

lldbinit-Xcode content:

```
command script import /Development/Qt/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/Resources/debugger/lldbbridge.py
```

Set the 'LLDB Init File' in the projects Scheme to the 'lldbinit-Xcode' shows:

```
error: type summary add takes one or more args.
  File "<string>", line 1
    <class.__doc__
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
warning: The provided class does not exist - please define it before attempting to use this synthetic provider
@
lldbversion="lldb-1103.0.22.4
Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)"@
@
state="enginesetupok"@
error: type summary add takes one or more args.
  File "<string>", line 1
    <class.__doc__
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
warning: The provided class does not exist - please define it before attempting to use this synthetic provider
Qt summary provider requires the pygdbmi module, please install using 'sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pygdbmi', and then restart Xcode.
```

In Qt Creator 4.10.0 there was a problem with lldbbridge.py and lldb's python version, but this has been fixed (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22955).

Setting the lldb python version to 2 (`defaults write com.apple.dt.lldb DefaultPythonVersion 2`) does not show any error but also no QString contents.

Do I also have to `easy_install pygdbmi`? But in which python to which install location?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install `pygdbmi`:

```
pip3 install pygdbmi
```

For some reason, it cannot be found in standard locations, so just copy it from `site-packages` to the `debuggers` folder where `lldbbridge.py` resides.

Then, switch lldb back to Python3:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.lldb DefaultPythonVersion 3
```

Finally, since `lldbbridge.py` is based on Python2, it is needed to patch it a little to work correctly:

```
@@ -2214,7 +2214,7 @@
 
             if encoding in text_encodings:
                 try:
-                    binaryvalue = summaryValue.decode('hex')
+                    binaryvalue = bytearray.fromhex(summaryValue)
                     # LLDB expects UTF-8
                     return "\"%s\"" % (binaryvalue.decode(encoding).encode('utf8'))
                 except:
```

Restart Xcode, and Qt debugging helpers should work now (tested with Xcode 12.3 on macOS 10.15.7).

Comment: Copying the pygdbmi into QtCreator got me one step closer to the solution. But every debug step prints `Qt summary warning: Failed to resolve type QObjectPrivate` / `QLocalePrivate` for every local variable.

Comment: There were some problems with cmake generating the Xcode project in legacy mode, switching it to the new mode, but it automatically switched it back etc... At the moment, there are no more lldb debug warnings, but some Qt objects still aren't properly shown (e.g. QDateTime, QSet, ...)

Comment: @Macintron if this is still a current problem, see my answer here for some alternatives to copying `pygdbmi`

Comment: @cycollins Thank you for the interesting idea. After a few fails I have a working solution.

Comment: Note: Use `/usr/bin/pip3 install pygdbmi` explicitly, so that you're not accidentally installing it for homebrew provided Python, which Xcode will not pick up.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new answer per se, but an update to those that precede it. [denis.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614287/denis-gz) suggests that perhaps there's a bug in `Xcode` or its `lldb` whereby its `python` interpreter cannot find the module `pygdbmi`. This is sort of my experience as well, because it didn't work for me either, but the folks who answered this question [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror) had some interesting ideas about how to run `pip` from within a `python` interpreter. Why would you want to do this, especially when you would have to quit that session anyway to import the installed module? Because the `Xcode lldb Python` interpreter is an entire environment onto itself, with its own `sys.path`, pointing entirely within the `Xcode.app` package. That's why it can't "see" your installed version of `pygdbmi`. One can argue about whether this is a bug, but it begs for some solutions, because `pygdbmi` is required by Qt's `lldbbridge.py` tool. I'm sure [denis.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614287/denis-gz)'s suggestion of copying the installed module from where `pip` installed it to within the contents of the `Qt Creator.app` bundle would work, but that didn't sit too well with me, so I looked for other solutions. When `lldb` is active within an `Xcode` debug session, you can fire up an interactive interpreter, exactly like the experience of using `python` from the command line, by using the lldb command `script`. You are then running a `python` interpreter within `Xcode`'s `lldb python` environment. Using the solution that was suggested by the answerer of the above SO question, you can install directly into this environment by the following sequence within the `lldb python` interpreter -

```
import pip._internal as pip
pip.main([ "install", "pygdbmi" ])
```

Now `pygdbmi` is tucked away within the `Xcode`'s bundle and is accessible to all `lldb python`. Now that's cool and all, but it's really not much better than copying the installed `pygdbmi` into `Qt Creator.app`'s bundle. If you were to update your `Xcode` (and how often does THAT happen?), this fix would probably not stick any more than when updating `Qt Creator`. So something I thought of after (but haven't tried yet), is the following: you can run a script in lldb python from the lldb command line with something like the following that you could put in your `.lldbinit` file -

```
script -l python -- sys.path += [ "directory/with/your/modules" ]
```

The path given will be outside of the `Xcode` bundle, and `Xcode` might nix this, but there's a setting for `Xcode` that says something about relaxing the "sanitary" build system model and allowing stuff from the larger environment in. If you were to use that, I feel confident the above would do the trick in the best way possible.

**Edit:**

Towards the end, I suggested a third path available by updating your `.lldbinit` file to augment the `sys.path` variable. I tried it, and it worked. First a correction from above. It is not wrong, but is unnecessary to import the `pip` in the way described above (`import pip._internal as pip`) to get access to the `main` method. It is sufficient to simply `import pip`. The single line I added to my `.lldbinit` file was -

```
script -l python -- import sys; sys.path += [ "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages" ]
```

After that I chose a module that had not been installed in Xcode's environment, but that had been in my larger environment in `site-packages` - `mercurial` for a random example. Back in Xcode, I started the `script` interpreter and was able to `import mercurial` without a complaint and without any special settings to "warn" Xcode that it's pristine environment was being opened up, so I just wanted to close that loop, having thrown it out there without a working example.

I have read in other answers while researching this, that there can be a per-scheme `lldb` init file specified somewhere in the scheme settings. I leave finding that as an exercise for the reader, but that might be a good place to play with these options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cycollins I found a working solution. In the meantime I'm using

- Xcode 12.5
- Qt 5.15.2
- Qt Creator 5.0
- macOS 11.6

The .lldbinit-Xcode

```
# pygdbmi isn't part of Xcodes/lldb/python config. Import it from an existing path
# make sure to have a similar python version for Xcode:
# script import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)
# install pygdbmi for this installation: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12/bin/pip3 install pygdbmi
script import sys; sys.path += [ "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages" ]

# ATTENTION, disables automatic loading of Python modules for DSYM!
settings set target.load-script-from-symbol-file false
command script import "/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/debugger/lldbbridge.py"
# requires 'defaults write com.apple.dt.lldb DefaultPythonVersion 3'
```

`/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/debugger/lldbbridge.py` has an output issue for QString (https://forum.qt.io/topic/118520/debugger-lldbbridge-py-used-with-xcode-11-6-issues-from-qt-creator-4-13).
Add `import codecs` at the beginning and apply this modification:

```
            if encoding in text_encodings:
                try:
-                    binaryvalue = summaryValue.decode('hex')
-                    # LLDB expects UTF-8
-                    return "\"%s\"" % (binaryvalue.decode(encoding).encode('utf8'))
+                    binaryvalue = bytes.fromhex(summaryValue)
+                    return "\"%s\"" % (codecs.decode(binaryvalue, encoding))
                except:
                    return "<failed to decode '%s' as '%s'>" % (summaryValue, encoding)
```

At least it is working again for QString, QVector, QList, QVariant. Still not working for QVector, QMap, QVariantList, etc.

Comment: You're doing better than I am. I would like to be able to get QString to work. I get an error - "error: <lldb wrapper prefix>:42:9: module 'std' not found"