# Installing Pillow on Python 3.8 Windows

Tags: python, xcode, python-imaging-library, python-3.8

**I am trying to install Pillow (7.1.2) on python (3.8 32bit) running on Windows.**

**The instructions** at *(https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) say:
"
*Windows Installation
We provide Pillow binaries for Windows compiled for the matrix of supported Pythons in both 32 and 64-bit versions in the wheel format. These binaries have all of the optional libraries included except for `raqm`, `libimagequant`, and `libxcb`:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

**I tried** writing 
`pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install --upgrade Pillow`
But whatever I write I get back an error:

> "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I am a bit new to python, maybe I'm missing something?
I read elsewhere that I need to install XCode first? maybe that's the problem?
If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong? do I need XCode? what is XCode?

thanks! :)

Comment: Xcode is an IDE for macOS. It's completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: (Generally, when you have a question like "what is X?" your first stop should either be your favourite search engine or Wikipedia.)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the reply,  of course I tried first looking up an answer on Google and other sites.

I am still having a hard time to understand exactly what are the steps I need to do in order to download PIP.

If you could please try to clerify (in beginner language ;)) what it is I need to do.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: The Google comment was about your "what is XCode?" question. The "Does this answer your question?" comment was the answer to your problem.