# SyntaxError when trying to install pygame

Tags: pygame

Here's what I get when I type in "py -3.8.3 -m pip install pygame"
(I have python 32 bit (ver 3.8.3 installed)

```
py -3.8.3 -m pip install pygame
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -3.8.3 -m pip install pygame
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Variations on this don't work either e.g. just

```
install pygame
```

Also gives the same error message.

Can anyone help me get it installed please?
I feel like a complete fool.

(p.s. I know some programming and that   will be a header file
allowing the processing of standard input and output.
I can't understand why the header file would not be initially installed.
At the command prompt, entering 2+3 gives 5, so I know python is at least
set up to process some input and output.
Is there an installation zip package for py game?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a command to be run in a system terminal, not an interactive Python console. I don't now what OS you're using, but open its terminal and run it there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror) Slightly different command, but this should be the same issue.

Comment: Thank you :)))))
Windows > eun > cmd
  then typing pip install python worked.
My kids will be happy now.
Thanks once more.

Comment: No problem. If that answered it, please accept the linked post so we can point future people there if they run into the same issue. Having your variation of the problem linking there will be helpful.