# Configuring Jupyterlab environment

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, pipenv, pyenv

I am following a tutorial on creating a basic webscraper utilising jupyterlab, I have been instructed to perform the following to setup my jupyterlab environment but cannot figure out this basic step for the life of me.

```
# Setup & Install Packages
# pyenv install 3.7.4
# pyenv local 3.7.4
# pipenv --python 3.7.4
# pipenv install requests
# pipenv install beautifulsoup4
# pipenv install pandas

# pipenv install jupyterlab
```

I understand that these commands are commented out when I try to run them I receive syntax errors in my jupyterlab environment,

```
    pyenv install 3.7.4
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone instruct me where these commands are intended to run in order to configure my jupyterlab environment appropriately?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: You say you get an error within your jupyterlab environment, but these are all things to do to install the jupyterlab environment in the first place. So does that you mean already have it installed? Then why are you doing these commands? What are you actually running that produces a syntax error?

Comment: In the bash/cmd shell... Possible duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)