# SyntaxError: invalid syntax: python -c "import numpy"

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have a `sample.py` python file, which contains this line:

```
python -c "import numpy"
```

Run Command:

```sh
$ python sample.py
```

When executed, the script got the error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone help me what is the issue with this line?

Comment: You can run `python -c "import numpy"` in the terminal. It's not meant to be code syntax.

Comment: I could not quickly find a good canonical for this very common beginner problem; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror is similar and has a couple of relevant answers, but is technically about `pip`, not about the `python` command itself.

Answer (score 0):

The content is not python, it's a command.

The content of sample.py should be just

```
import numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

`python -c ...` calls python from a shell, and executes `-c`'s argument by python. If you want that in a script, use a shell script, not a python script.
Alternatively, if you're running it with `python` anyway, drop the `python -c`, and just keep the python code (`import numpy`).