# Can I specify install time dependencies for pip?

Tags: python, pip

I'm looking for a way to mimic `pyproject.toml` behavior for `pip install`.

`pyproject.toml` can specify build-time dependencies, e.g. if a `setup.py` needs extra packages to build:

**setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import setup
import colorama # e.g. - non-standard package
setup(...)
```

This can be handled by a **pyproject.toml**

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "colorama",  # required for running custom code in setup.py
    "setuptools>=40.8.0",  # required by doc (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/)
    "wheel", # required by doc (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/)
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__" # required by doc (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/)
```

which will allow `python -m build` to run.

However, this doesn't solve the issue for `pip install <path>`, due to pyproject.toml only handling build.

**Is there a way to do so for installation as well?**

My only thoughts are

1. add a wrapper that installs the required pkg which I don't want to (hoping to stick with just `pip install`)
2. call `subprocess.run(f'pip install {pkg}'); importlib.reload(pkg)` which is hacky

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/39231583/10875953 solves it.

Comment: @john-hen The OP means "build-time dependencies" and the difference is that regular dependencies are used at run-time but build-time dependencies are imported in `setup.py` so they must be installed into the current environment before `setup.py` is called.

Comment: @john-hen AFIU the OP means that `pyproject.toml` is not used during `pip install <path>`

Comment: @phd indeed. However, retrying it made me question this assumption. It would seem that pip install does use, but python setup.py doesn't. Which still leaves me in a pickle, because I want to call setup.py directly but have the dependencies installed

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted the asnswer in the comments, but since that's depricated here's the official answer:

```
from pip._internal.commands import create_command

package_names = ['colorama']  # packages to install
arguments = ['--upgrade'] # extra arguments
command = create_command("install", isolated=True) # don't know what isolated does, so maybe that needs to change
command.main(package_names + arguments) # execute it
```

Note that this is the original function, and it's probably safer to call al those functions

```
def main(args=None):
    # type: (Optional[List[str]]) -> int
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]

    # Configure our deprecation warnings to be sent through loggers
    # deprecation.install_warning_logger() # don't call this

    autocomplete()

    try:
        cmd_name, cmd_args = parse_command(args)
    except PipError as exc:
        sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
        sys.stderr.write(os.linesep)
        sys.exit(1)

    # Needed for locale.getpreferredencoding(False) to work
    # in pip._internal.utils.encoding.auto_decode
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
    except locale.Error as e:
        # setlocale can apparently crash if locale are uninitialized
        logger.debug("Ignoring error %s when setting locale", e)
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))

    return command.main(cmd_args)
```