# How To Work With SharePoint Files with Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, pip

Using Python 3.6.3.
Ultimately I am trying to work with files on SharePoint
My Python script works perfectly as long as local drive (C:)

Searching led me to [this](https://mahaboob.medium.com/accessing-files-from-sharepoint-using-python-c337f61e9f02) article which tells me to install
pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client

which I tried which then gave me this error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install Office365 REST Python Client
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any thoughts how I can correctly use python script on SharePoint files?

Thanks
w

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548165/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: Type `pip help` at a cmd prompt for usage instructions.

Comment: it seems you are trying to execute the "pip install" command from the python file but it should be executed in the cmd

Comment: You need to add dashes between the words in your pip statement `pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client`. In the original line it thinks you are trying to load multiple individual libraries called `Office365`, `REST`, `Python`, and `Client`.