# syntax error when trying to install agentpy

Tags: python

Goal: install agentpy to a Google Colab notebook.

Current code:

```
pip install agentpy
import agentpy as ap
import numpy as np
```

Problem: invalid syntax on line 1.

Comment: `pip install agentpy` is a command to be entered at a shell prompt.  It is not python code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `pip` in a python file. It is meant to be used on a command line. Since you are on Google Colab this should work:

```
!pip install agentpy
import agentpy as ap
import numpy as np
```

You just have to add an exclamation mark to get it to run in a shell on Google Colab. If you are not using Google Colab the solution is to just enter the command on a command line and your package should be installed.