# How to install the latest version of the library plotly.express in Code Workbook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python, plotly-express, foundry-code-workbooks

In Code Workbook, I would like to install the version 5.11.0 of the library plotly.express.

I tried to install the version 5.11.0 of the library plotly.express  in the section global code with this code:

```
$ pip3 install plotly==5.11.0
```

but I got this error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: "*...with this code...*" I'm not sure if you meant "command" instead of "code", but the `pip install` line is not code, but a command, and is not meant to be executed on the Python shell or part of Python code. That could be why you are getting a syntax error. (I don't know anything about Code Workbooks though, not sure exactly where you running pip commands)

Comment: Might be related: [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```bash
pip install --upgrade plotly
```

or

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade plotly
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i tried with  both  `pip install --upgrade plotly
`   and  `pip3 install --upgrade plotly` but it doesn't seem to work, i still have the same error "  SyntaxError: invalid syntax ".

Comment: and if you execute `apt install pip` first? Or reinstall python?

Comment: @melissame For the syntax error when doing `pip install ...`, please check that you are _not_ running these commands inside the Python shell. You have to exit Python shell first, and run `pip install` on the regular console/terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8548030/2745495