# Python syntax for path in the package arxiv_latex_cleaner?

Tags: python, path, tex

I'm trying to delete all comments from a .tex document. The package `arxiv_latex_cleaner` is supposed to do this automatically and remove unnecessary files. I'm using the syntax as stated in the [package description](https://github.com/google-research/arxiv-latex-cleaner) and the [arXiv website](https://info.arxiv.org/help/faq/whytex.html), where they say to type:

`arxiv_latex_cleaner /path/to/tex/`

I'm using Sypder 5.4.1 and Python 3.10.9: after typing `import arxiv_latex_cleaner` in the script file and pressing F9 I am typing in the console:

`arxiv_latex_cleaner 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\paper'`

where `paper` is the folder where the .tex file is. I've tried multiple combinations such as "/Users/MyName/Desktop/paper/" and many others, I always get: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

**ANSWER:**

Since the question was flagged as a duplicate of [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548030/why-does-pip-install-inside-python-raise-a-syntaxerror) I wanted to point out that:

- I tried out using the Windows CMD shell for the command, it returned a not found error
- While my error was indeed using the python shell console (in Spyder) instead of Windows CMD, I had to add Anaconda to the system path first. I did this via:
  `RUN > sysdm.cpl > advanced > Environment Variables > System variables > Path > Edit > New` and entered `C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\Scripts`
- also, the command `pip install package_name` works perfectly fine in the python shell console, hence it was not immediately obvious to me that I shouldn't be using it for the `arxiv_latex_cleaner` command above; hence the above question did not directly answer my problem.

Comment: The command is something you would type at your terminal prompt, not inside Python.